# Progress Bar Not Accepting any Month or day values above 12

Tags: php

I have a interesting issue with my code. What it is supposed to do it workout the progress from one day to the other and give a progress in a percent. Except if I use a day  with a value above 12 when submitting (EG: 2015-11-**16**) it will give 100% every time no matter how long until that date. I have attached both code sections.

INSERTING INTO DATABASE:

```
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$title = $_POST['title'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$completion= ''.$_POST['completion'].' 9:00:00';
$progress = date('Y-m-j h:i:s');
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `taskname`, `details`, `completion`, `startdate`) VALUES ('', '$title', '$detail', '$completion', '$progress')");
echo $sql;
} else {
echo "";
}
```

DISPLAYING FROM DATABASE:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$date1 = strtotime($row['completion']);
$date2 = strtotime($row['startdate']);

$today = time();
$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
$dateDiffForToday = $today - $date1;

$percentage = $dateDiffForToday / $dateDiff * 100;
$percentageRounded = round($percentage);

echo $percentageRounded . '%';
```

It probably is a every easy solution but I cant see one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$date1 = strtotime($row['completion']);
$date2 = strtotime($row['startdate']);

$today = time();
$dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
$dateDiffForToday = $today - $date1;

$percentage = ($dateDiffForToday / $dateDiff) * 100;
$percentageRounded = round($percentage);

echo $percentageRounded . '%';
}
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. However it seems if the year is above 2015 it breaks. @coderleo

Comment: @LaughingQuoll Try using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead of strtotime(), as it (DateTime) appears to be the better way to handle times.

You might also want to look into [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Comment: dont worry. I got the rows around the wrong way. If I switch them over its fine. Thanks